# Why am i getting the error 404 for my get-request that should return af list of all users

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Im trying to get a list of all users for my endpoint, but it returns the 404 error.
As you can see in the code, i have a model for my user, a controller for user, router for user and the index file, which is my startpoint in the application.

This is my model for User.ts:

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

export enum Role {
    manager = "Manager",
    clerk = "Clerk",
    guest = "Guest"
}

export interface User{
    firstName: string;
    middleName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    role: Role;
    password: string;
    salt: string;
}

export const schema = new Schema<User>({
    firstName: { type: String, required: true },
    middleName: { type: String, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    role: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    salt: { type: String, required: true},
  });
```

This is my userController.ts:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { schema } from "../models/User";
import { join } from 'path'

const X5U = 'http://localhost:3000/auth-rsa256.key.pub';
const PATH_PRIVATE_KEY = join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'auth-rsa.key');

const usersConnection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/users')
const UserModel = usersConnection.model('User', schema)

const listUsers = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    let result = await UserModel.find({}).lean().exec();
    res.json(result);
  };

module.exports = {
    listUsers
};
```

This is my userRouter.ts:

```
import { Router } from "express";
const userController = require('../controller/userController')

const userRouter = Router();

userRouter.get('/users', userController.listUsers);

module.exports = userRouter;
```

And this is my index.ts:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(express.text());

app.use('/users', require("./router/userRouter"));

app.listen(port, () => {
  return console.log(`Express is listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Do you mind posting your project folder structure? pzaenger's answer is right, but if that doesn't fix it, something else is off and more detail is needed IMO. If nothing works, I recommend you to use the npm package 'express-generator' to create a simple express app, and start converting it to your current one, running at each step to verify it works. Maybe that way, you can find where you have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In userRouter.ts change the following line:

```
userRouter.get('/', userController.listUsers);
```

Since you do `app.use('/users', require("./router/userRouter"));` in index.ts, the path is already correct and acts as an base path for the routes added within userRouter.ts. Otherwise it would be /users/users.

Comment: I also tried with the endpoint /users/users in postman but it still gave error 404 and now i tried your suggestion but it also gave error 404.

Answer (score 0):

Actually maybe it will work. I have now realized that the changes I do in my application are not saved and I dont know why. For example, I have changed my port to 2000, but it is still running the old code which you can see in the terminal, because it is printing port 3000. So when I ran your suggestion, it really didnt run it, it just ran the old one....
And I have previously generated a public and a private rsa key and printed it out in the consol and then saved them to a file in my project and deleted the code. But somehow it still shows the generated private and public keys.

[Code and consol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ohXj.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).